# Keeping talisman makers from being overpowered?

Tags: magic, super-powers

A quick glossary to show how the magic works:

Spell - The usage of materials to magically produce an event. Not widely used because it takes time and physical resources.

Talisman - An item that can be used to produce or amplify magic. Common, because a talisman expands a mage's range of magical abilities and bring magic to non-mages and is thus in high demand.

Power - The ability to use magic without needing to cast a spell or use a talisman. May be learned or inborn. As common as any magical ability is and different for everybody.

Feel - The ability to learn spells and powers by detecting magical properties as well as predicting magical connections and reactions. Each mage has a *feel* for certain areas of magic, such as plants, minerals, the weather or transformation.

Each method of magic is based on the same principle - re-arranging the invisible force of magic within oneself or in one's to create a certain type of magic and activating it to create a reaction.
Most mages have powers of shapeshifting into one animal -different for everybody- without a *feel* for shapeshifting because they can manipulate the magic inside themselves. But a mage with a *feel* for transformation could turn into anything they want to be, or even change somebody else with enough skill and practice because they can "grab" the magic, manipulate it and then activate it to make the change happen.

The idea in question is for a mage to have a *feel* for transferring and storing magic in items to make them into talismans that essentially serve as transferable powers. Like making a hat that gives the wearer the ability to set things on fire with magic or a cotton quilt that's bulletproof.
Given this system of magic, is there a way for a mage to have a *feel* for making talismans without making them OP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Limit by "feel" (affinity)

You can only make talisman if you have feel of the required magic. For example, to make a Fireball talisman, you must have both feel for talisman and fire.

### Limit by mana/magic quantity

You can only manipulate certain amount of magic into a talisman. Think about this as "magic strength". If you are not well-versed in making talisman, you can only make low-level talisman from low-level spell or power.

### Limit by talisman material

You can only enchant certain spell or power into specific material. For example, you can only enchant wind magic into silk clothes, or fire magic only for dragon scale armor.

Or you can give low capacity to low quality material, meaning they can only have low level enchantment or fewer enchantment.

### Limit by complexity of talisman making

The process of creating talisman is very cumbersome and need great precision. 
It also takes long time and preparation, not including collecting the required ingredients and materials.

Beginner to talisman making often accidentally create a catastrophe when trying to enchant talisman, so it requires a strict certification to be able to legally produce talisman.

### Limit by talisman charges

Similar to a battery, a talisman can only be used a number of times before depleting its magical energy. High level talisman requires a lot of magic and usually can only be used once. It can only be recharged by certain individuals (cannot be charged by general magic/mana)

### *Pick one.*

Comment: `Pick one` or two...

Comment: @Draco18s if you really don't want people to make talisman, why not `all` of them?

Comment: I was going to put "...or more" on there, but figured that was redundant. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I understand english but I can't write very much so I write in spanish. You could use translator.

Una manera de limitar el overpowering de un mago haciendo talismanes es que el talismán guarde parte del poder del mago. De ésta forma un mago tiene un poder limitado y mientras parte de su poder esté en el talismán él no puede usarlo apra otra cosa.

---

Translation:

One way to limit the overpowering of a magician by making talismans is for the talisman to retain some of the mage's power. In this way a magician has limited power and while part of his power is in the talisman he can not use it for anything else.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Nico. Please note that the Worldbuilding community uses English as a neutral communication language, as a majority of its users are relatively fluent. I've added an English translation for your post, provided by Google translation services. In the future, please consider using such services prior to posting a non-English answer. Feel free to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of how the site works.

Comment: This is by far the most creative answer, and I'll definitely use a variant on it  in my story.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this. A talisman is not an object in the way that a pocketwatch is an object. The talisman is both an object and a "feel". A person can have a "feel" for making talismans, but this person would have no "feel" for anything else. The talisman-maker would not make talismans by enchanting any random object, the talisman-maker would instead, for instance, make a fire talisman by burning rowan wood and pouring the ashes into a hollow ring with a stone of obsidan. The mage in question would be able to make as many talismans as necessary, but would have to own the required ingredients for a spell, **AND** have a "feel" for talisman-making. Unlike spells, talismans would be reusable, and the magic would never decay. An interesting possibility for this would be to have an ancient, utopian civilization that existed for thousands of years before falling to conquering outsiders. During their reign, they made some of the most powerful talismans the world ever has or will see. If these include time or mind control talismans, they will be sought after by every person in your world.